# Get title from array using an id

Tags: php

Probaly a simple one for you but I have the following array that contains all the categories from a database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Fitness News
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt tempor nunc, sit amet facilisis metus molestie nec. Nulla varius justo et felis euismod bibendum. Vestibulum suscipit tempus viverra. Mauris eros lorem, posuere eget mattis et, euismod id metus. In ac dignissim ligula. fdsfdsfdsfds fdsf fsd
            [image1] => test
            [image1_title] => test
            [created] => 2012-03-26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Recommended Products
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tincidunt tempor nunc, sit amet facilisis metus molestie nec. Nulla varius justo et felis euismod bibendum. Vestibulum suscipit tempus viverra. Mauris eros lorem, posuere eget mattis et, euismod id metus. In ac dignissim ligula.gdsfdsfdsfdsfds
            [image1] => H
            [image1_title] => H
            [created] => 2012-03-25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => New Category
            [description] => This is a new category
            [image1] => 
            [image1_title] => 
            [created] => 2012-03-13
        )

)
```

Now what I have is bassically a category ID, but from this I would like to get the category title from the above array.

Comment: You want to extract the category title by Id ?

Comment: @ssx that's kinda what it says in the question title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of searching the old array**, I'd reformat the old array so it's much more usable:

```
$categories = array();

foreach( $old_categories as $item)
    $categories[ $item['id'] ] = $item;
```

Now you can access anything to want based on ID. For example:

```
$id = 2;
echo $categories[ $id ]['title'];
echo $categories[ $id ]['description'];
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if you want to look up multiple IDs, but if you want to look up just one, using array_search or looping is probably faster.

Comment: True, but if you only needed one ID, the query from the database should only return one record.

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = array_search ($category_id, $array);
echo $array [$key] ['title'];
```

or

```
$category_id = 1;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if ($val ['id'] == $category_id) {
        $title = $val ['title'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = array_search($categoryId, $array);
$title = $array[$key]['title'];
```